# How to download full file from FTP using talend openstudio

Tags: ftp, talend

I am currently using talend open studio to download files from ftp to local machine. This is a scheduled task. Some times I am not able to download full files from FTP since at the same time files are being uploading to ftp.

Is there any way to check file fully uploaded to FTP and download using talend ?

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation we check last modified time before downloading, let say donwload only 5mn old files. This can be done using `tFTPFileProperties`.